# How can I rebuild an index on table with 100 million rows without a wait time out?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014

I have the following table with ~100 million rows:

```
CREATE TABLE Result (
    MetricId int NOT NULL,
    PeriodId int NOT NULL,
    Value decimal (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Result PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (MetricId ASC,PeriodId ASC)
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Result_PeriodId ON Result (PeriodId ASC)
```

My analysis of this situation (and I'm by no means a DBA) is:

1. The NC index should have `Value` as an included column. We are
   seeing queries that filter by `PeriodId` use the NC index but then
   need a Key Lookup on the PK to get the value. I think this will give
   us much better query performance.
2. The NC Index does not need `MetricId` in the key after `PeriodId`
   because SQL Server implicitly includes any columns in the clustered
   PK index.
3. As an aside: the main filter we use in queries is `PeriodId` therefore it would
   be best to have the PK around the other way (ie. PeriodId,MetricId).
   I also believe `PeriodId` is more selective (?) in that it would
   make sense to filter first by `PeriodId` to get rid of the most
   rows during a query.

**My question is then - how can I create or rebuild the following index?**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Result_PeriodId ON Result (PeriodId ASC) INCLUDE (Value)
```

I have tried editing the existing index through Management Studio which requires a rebuild, and that times out after 5-10 minutes. It's a 'Wait Timeout' I believe.

I have tried creating a brand new index through Management Studio with the same result.

I have tried putting the database in Single User mode and creating the new index. Same result.

Upgrading to Enterprise is not an option for me.

How can I create this index on such a large table?

Comment: Run the script through a new query window in SSMS. Not through the visual designer.

Comment: @martinsmith Thanks - that did the trick. Feel free to add as an answer if you'd like. It took 15 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Community Wiki answer for the solution originally provided in a question comment:</sub>

> [Martin Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3690/martin-smith): Run the script through a new query window in SSMS. Not through the visual designer.